# Elasticsearch sort by nested count

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a product with links, mapped

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "product": {
      "properties": {
        "links": {
          "type": "nested"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I sort on the length of the links? I've tried the following but it does not work:

```
{
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "script": "doc['links'].values.length",
      "order": "desc",
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

The error I'm getting is: `["org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup.get(LeafDocLookup.java:81)","org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup.get(LeafDocLookup.java:39)","doc['links'].values.length"," ^---- HERE"],"script":"doc['links'].values.length","lang":"painless","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"No field found for [links] in mapping with types []"}}}]},"status":500}`

Comment: A good idea would be to also index the length of the `links` array in the top-level document instead of resorting to scripting which will kill your performance

Comment: Could you explain to me how I would add an index to the length of `links`?

Comment: When you create the document simply create another integer field which contains `links.length` and you can sort by it easily without resorting to scripting

Comment: Is that being set automatically by elastic? Or do I have to manually increment that number every time I add a link?

Comment: You need to do it inside your indexing application. Or you could also do it using an [ingest pipeline with a script processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/script-processor.html) but the former is more advisable since more performant.